# Button click throws nullpointerexception in fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Im getting an error when I press the button in my fragment view. The button is rendered but when I click it I get the following error:

> 09-23 18:29:01.242    9332-9332/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at foit.startingpoint.nl.androiddrawer.LocatiesFragment.onCreateView(LocatiesFragment.java:28)

```
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LocatiesFragment.this.getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);            }
    });
    
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locaties, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Is `button` in the xml inflated in your `Activity` or in `fragment_locaties.xml`?

Comment: fragment_locaties.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your initializing is incorrect, you must do as following code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locaties, container, false);
           Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
           button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent); 
             }
    });

    return view;
}
```

as `onCreateView` not finished `getView` is null in your code so you must create one view and use that.

Comment: This is why I inflate layout in #onCreateView and setup views in #onViewCreated.

Comment: this solution has one problem and it's that when you inflate your view in `onCreateView` and other code in `onViewCreated` you Must hold one instance of View in your fragment, but your solution is very good

Comment: Could someone explain to me exactly what this does and what the problem was? Im a beginner=(

Comment: I think best help is showing developer site but for one guid, fragment has been attached to acivity, so until onCreateView layout has not been initialized, so you can't use getView method because view has not been initialized yet, so for solving this problem you must create on View and inflate your layout then use that for finding you view ( as I used in my code ), another way is use `onViewCreated()` instead of `onCreateView`, so you just inflate your layout in `onCreateView` and initialize your widget and other thing in `onViewCreated`, both way worked but first way is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply getView() from nowhere when finding button id. First layout is inflated.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locaties, container, false);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
...
return view;
```